# Is it possible to exchange search patterns in vim?

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

Is there a way, built-in or with a plugin, that I can swap any number of two different patterns on an arbitrary range using a regex?

Maybe something `:s`-style like `:{range}exchange/{pattern-1}/{pattern-2}/{flags}`?

Example:

```
foo bar
bar foo bar
```

hypothetical command swaps `foo` and `bar`

```
bar foo
foo bar foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of an old question I cannot found anymore but for which I've a trace (through a solution): https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/rotate_substitute.vim

```
:command! -bang -nargs=1 -range CycleSubstitute <line1>,<line2>call s:CycleSubstitute("<bang>", <f-args>)


" no back ref supported; makes no sense
function! s:CycleSubstitute(bang, repl_arg) range
  let do_loop = a:bang != "!"
  let sep = a:repl_arg[0]
  let fields = split(a:repl_arg, sep)
  let cleansed_fields = map(copy(fields), 'substitute(v:val, "\\\\[<>]", "", "g")')
  " build the action to execute
  let action = '\=s:DoCycleSubst('.do_loop.',' . string(cleansed_fields) . ', "^".submatch(0)."$")'
  " prepare the :substitute command
  let args = [join(fields, '\|'), action ]
  let cmd = a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 's'
        \. sep . join(fields, '\|')
        \. sep . action
        \. sep . 'g'
  " echom cmd
  " and run it
  exe cmd
endfunction

function! s:DoCycleSubst(do_loop, fields, what)
  let idx = (match(a:fields, a:what) + 1) % len(a:fields)
  return a:fields[idx]
endfunction
```

Which could be used with: `%CycleSubstitute/foo/bar`  in your example.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! It's going in my plugins (with license of course). A little followup because I can't read vimscript very well: what do `RotateSubstitute`, `Translate`, and `Do____` do in that script?

Comment: IIRC, `:RotateSubstitute` replaces text matching the pattern with the first replacement first, then within the second, then with the third, and so on. `:Translate` is just like `tr(anslate)` unix command on range of lines. Your should see the Q/A's they answer in the first links at the top of the file. `s:Doxxx`  are support functions

Answer (score 1):

Great though it would be, there is no exchange command in Vim and the
usual approach here is to perform A-->B, C-->A, B-->C instead of the direct
but impossible A<-->C. Of course, one needs to guarantee that the intermediate
B value is not present in the file. So use something weird enough for B,
for example, `@#%`:

```
:%s/foo/@#%/g|%s/bar/foo/g|%s/@#%/bar/g
```

If you don't want to take the risk of `@#%` being present in the file,
adapt [this use of Sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192083)
to:

```
:%!sed 's/foo/\n/g;s/bar/foo/g;s/\n/bar/g'
```

As described in the linked answer, Sed's pattern space is guaranteed to
have no newline characters, so this last command is certain to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Use capture groups.

```
:s/\v(pattern1)(.*)(pattern2)/\3\2\1/
```

You need to capture the text in between to reference it during substitution.

Comment: That only works if the patterns are in a same line and in the order specified. I'm afraid OP asks for swapping all X with Y and all Y with X irrespective of order or line.

Comment: @Quasímodo i think OP clarified after Spidey posted the answer, which was otherwise correct